# How to compile ROS2 for another OS

Tags: compilation, operating-system, cross-compiling, ros2

I'm writing my master thesis on Computer Engineering about ROS2. I learned a lot thanks to tutorials on https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/. I tried ROS2 on my Ubuntu 18 and 16 machines but I would like to insert in my thesis a general guide to compile ros2 for others operative systems (not specific). I would like to know where if could find a guide about "compiling ros2 for others OS".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-cross-compilation/6834
As there are some discussions about how to cross-compile ROS2. Some people cross-compiled ROS2 for iOS, Android,..
Hopefully a tutorial will emerge from those discussions.

However, if you need to compile ROS2 to a non-supported OS (Fedora, or others,..) you will need to make sure you have all the dependencies necessary: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Linux-Development-Setup/ (same library version,..).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll check. :)